# Use kirchhoff's second law to deduce the resistance R of the resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, voltage

[image]

Using what I learned so far, i constructed an equation like this:

$$30V=(I_{1}\times 20\Omega)+10V+(0.2A\times 10\Omega)+(I
_{3}\times 10\Omega)+(0.5A\times R)$$

Which is clearly not solvable on its own. What am I missing from the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well basically your missing some additional equations. The current coming out of the $10 \Omega$ resistor is the same as the one going into it. Hence $I_3$ in your equation would be just $0.5A$. Similar thing for $I_1$: The current going through the $20 \Omega$ resistor is $0.2A$. Note that the power supply also doesn't alter the current only the voltage. Hope that helps.

Best regards,

Stefan